# HTML loads before CSS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My code is loading the HTML before the CSS, so my site looks like a skeleton at first. After a second or two, the CSS kicks in and my site is rendered how it should be. Is there some way to have both my HTML and CSS render at the same time, so the site doesn't look out of order at first?
I have an external CSS file that is linked to my .PHP file. This is how the beginning of my code looks like:

```
<?php
require_once "../../universal.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--UNIVERSAL HEADER CSS-->
    <link href="/universal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--STYLE SHEET FOR THIS FILE-->
    <link href="/entertainment/template.css?ts=&lt;?=time()?&gt;&quot;" rel=
    "stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--STYLE SHEET FOR FOOTER-->
    <link href="/footer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

Comment: Note that `<!--Universal Header-->` is **not** commented out in your PHP. To comment in php it would be `//Universal Header` or `/* Universal header */` Failure to comment out correctly may be causing other issues.